# Post xml data to chartmogul webhook [php]

Tags: php, curl, http-post, webhooks, recurly

**Requirement :**

I need to setup a relay to forward the webhook from my server to the ChartMogul endpoint - this usually just involves adding a few lines of code to the script that is already receiving the webhook on your server.

**Trouble i'm Facing**

I'm facing a trouble while POSTing data to chartmogul webhook using cURL utility in PHP. Here is the code :

**Line of Code**

```
    function updateChartmogul($xml) {
        $url = 'https://app.chartmogul.com/api/events/****/Yi**********ArS***'; //Chartmogul webhook url
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    updateChartmogul('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new_subscription_notification>
  <account>
    <account_code>1</account_code>
    <username>test1</username>
    <email>test@test.com</email>
    <first_name>testing</first_name>
    <last_name>demo</last_name>
    <company_name>demo</company_name>
  </account>
  <subscription>
    <plan>
      <plan_code>plan-b</plan_code>
      <name>Plan-b</name>
    </plan>
    <uuid>2e3504c45933020c68368648ee998dd2</uuid>
    <state>active</state>
    <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    <total_amount_in_cents type="integer">2000</total_amount_in_cents>
    <subscription_add_ons type="array"/>
    <activated_at type="datetime">2015-04-17T07:13:20Z</activated_at>
    <canceled_at type="datetime" nil="true"></canceled_at>
    <expires_at type="datetime" nil="true"></expires_at>
    <current_period_started_at type="datetime">2015-04-17T07:13:20Z</current_period_started_at>
    <current_period_ends_at type="datetime">2015-05-07T07:13:20Z</current_period_ends_at>
    <trial_started_at type="datetime">2015-04-17T07:13:20Z</trial_started_at>
    <trial_ends_at type="datetime">2015-05-07T07:13:20Z</trial_ends_at>
  </subscription>
</new_subscription_notification>');
```

I'm getting this response :

```
output of $data :

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.7.7
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 07:35:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: "444bcb3a3fcf83***467f27e1d6"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 05c27dd5-***-42bd-99ab-b506446d1305
X-Runtime: 0.026330
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0

output of $response : ok
```

While i'm getting response as "ok". I'm not getting any reflect in my data in my chartmogul account. Am i doing it right way ?

**Note** 
I've passed hard code xml data which is same as what i'm getting from recurly every time the recurly webhook get called.

Answer (score 1):

Nick from ChartMogul here.

It looks like you are using the wrong encoding for the packets you send to ChartMogul.  You should use UTF-8 for request encoding.

XML is the format of the data, UTF-8 should be the encoding of the data.